# How to make Italic font of heading text?

Tags: fonts, header-footer, italic

I have used

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
\markboth{#1}{}}
```

to show heading information. I need to make text font in Italic. Please tell me how can i achive that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the command `\itshape` in the first argument of `\markboth`:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\itshape #1}{}}
```

or even using `\textit` works:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\textit{#1}}{}}
```

Comment: Thanks KersouMan